# Handling a "pending" user workflow

Tags: entity-framework, database-design

Consider the following structure:

#### Organization

```
Id
Name
```

#### User

```
Id
OrganizationId
CreatedAt
Name
Email
Verified
```

The first user will also create the organization, thus their account will already be verified. Subsequent users will require an existing **verified** user to verify their account.

Using entity framework, is their a more eloquent and less bug-prone solution than having check the verified flag in almost every query? eg. something like:

```
from u in Db.Users
where u.OrganizationId == 1 && u.CreatedAt >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14d) && u.Verfied
select u
```

An option I have considered would be creating a second table, something like the below and making the `OrganizationId` on the user `null` but it somehow doesn't seem quite right!

#### OrganizationPendingUsers

```
Id
OrganizationId
UserId
```

Comment: The least pervasive solution I can think of would be to have a property `IQueryable<User> VerifiedUsers` in the DbContext (`Db`), returning `Users.Where(u => u.Verified)`. But it would not work with nested `User` collections in other entities, if there are any.

Answer (score 1):

I would design this by having another DBSet but take it a bit further than you suggest. Propably something like PendingRequest

```
Id
OrganizationId
CreatedAt (?)
Name
Email
```

The difference is I would not add the user to the Users before they are verified. This cleanely separates requests and "real users" which mean there is almost no risk that you will accidently include unverified users in your code as that would require you to join over another DbSet.

Once someone verifies a request I would simply create a user from that request and delete the request.